# Regular Expression to remove everything but characters and numbers

Tags: java, regex

I would like to remove everything but the Characters a-z,A-Z and 0-9 from a String so I need to create a regular expression for Java's `string.replaceAll(regex, "");`

The old string would look like this:

```
MAX EUK_1334-PP/B+
```

The new string should look like this:

```
MAXEUK1334PPB
```

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There's probably a more concise regex, but this will certainly work:

```
string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
```

Comment: +1 for fast answer. I wasn't as fast typing my answer on the iPhone ;-)

Comment: It may be faster if you let it match multiple characters, so string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "").

Comment: Tried string 24\7.Strangely it returns 24.Why?

Comment: Did you try the string literal `"24\7"` or `"24\\7"`?  The former is characters `2`, `4`, and ASCII character 7 (bell).  A missing backslash could definitely explain your result.

Comment: @sandy that's the whole point, slashes are not allowed, why would it be included?

Comment: @momo I believe he was more focused on the 7 not appearing, rather than the backslash not appearing.

Answer (score 19):

```
string.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", "");
```

Comment: as @MRAB later mentioned I decided to replace several characters at once for better perfomance

Answer (score 2):

```
String test = "MAX EUK_1334-PP/B+";     
test = test.replaceAll("[\\W_]", "");
System.out.println(test + "\n");
```

Printed Result :

```
MAXEUK1334PPB
```

Comment: Did you know that `\W` doesn't match the “`_`” character either?

Comment: This regex will include characters wanted *plus* the underscore.  The brackets are redundant, too.

Comment: This results in `unexpected char: 'W'` and 
`Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )`

Comment: corrected the regular expression and added more clear example.

Answer (score 1):

Some are forgetting the "_" char:

`String regex = "[_\\W]";`

```
public class RegexFun2 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String test = "MAX EUK_1334-PP/B+";

      String regex = "[_\\W]";

      String result = test.replaceAll(regex, "");
      System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

But still I think the OP is cheating himself by not demonstrating that he tried first and posting his attempt in his original question.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Almost identical to OP I'd tried this with [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/)

```js
const filteredString = R.replace (/[^a-zA-Z0-9 "-/]/g, '');
```

to remove everything but characters (plus: "-/). Strange thing that this regex didn't remove dots (.) if constructor is not used. Everything else works like a charm.

So, for the OP should be

```js
const filteredString = R.replace (/([^a-zA-Z0-9])|(_)/g, '');
```

or using the RegExp constructor

```js
const onlyChars = new RegExp ('([^a-zA-z0-9])|(_)', 'g');
const filteredString = R.replace (onlyChars, '');
```

And to use it:

```js
const oldString = `MAX EUK_1334-PP/B+`;
filteredString (oldString); -> "MAXEUK1334PPB"
```

**UPDATE**: my mistake, I should wrote something wrong the first time, because the dot is actually removed. The character that this regex don't delete is _, so I added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII values of chars:

```
while(!end of string){
    if(valueOfChar is between 48-57 or 65-90 or 97-122)
          write it to your string
}
```

This may help, but I don't know if you're supposed to write the code with `replaceAll`.
Both `replaceAll` and this code works with the same performance (`O(n)`).